# Flower identification (England, late May)

Tags: species-identification

I took this photo near Stratford upon Avon by the side of a road. Can anyone identify this flower?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a closeup of the petals?

Comment: @dd3 Unfortunately not, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MY guess would be *[Centranthus ruber coccineus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centranthus_ruber)*, also known as red valerian. See this picture (from [here](http://imgkid.com/centranthus-ruber-coccineus.shtml)):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could be [pink allium](http://www.bhg.com/gardening/plant-dictionary/bulb/allium/), considering the thickness of the stem?

Comment: Allium is an onion; they're monocots (would have blade-like leaves from base, not stem.)